# Call function when input is changed on text box?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm trying to create a button that changes color when username and password fields have both been entered with some sort of input (IE; neither username or password text boxes are empty)

Is there a way I can get a function to trigger when input of a text box is changed in NativeScript? I've asked at the NativeScript slack, among other sites but I don't seem to get a reply ever.

I thought this was a relatively simple request, especially when I'm using vanilla JS. Surely it must be simpler than using a framework such as Angular or Vue?

I do not want to use a framework, I am looking for a way to do this with plain JS. What have I tried? I've tried `onChange=""`, `textChange=""`, `change=""` but none seem to work.

Comment: Probably something [like this](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/text-field#binding), but it's hard to say since you don't have any example code so it's not clear what you're using.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using plain JavaScript / TypeScript without any framework, then you must add your `textChange` listener after `loaded` event.

**XML**

```
<TextField loaded="onTextFieldLoaded"></TextField>
```

**JS**

```
function onTextFieldLoaded(args) {
  const textField = args.object;
  textField.off("loaded");
  textField.on("textChange", onTextChange);
}

function onTextChange(args) {
  console.log("Changed: " + args.value);
}
```

[Here is a Playground Sample.](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=rHmPwY&v=1)

Comment: I implemented your code into my app and it console logs, although the textbox seems to cancel out the character I enter. Here is my playground sample: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=euJOGP

Answer (score 0):

You can use onkeyup event to trigger the validation for the form.

See the Snippet below:

```js
document.addEventListener("load", function(){
  
});

function validate(event){
  if(document.getElementById("username").value.trim()!="" && document.getElementById("password").value.trim()!=""){
    document.getElementById("btn").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }else{ 
    document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

```css
.enable{
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="username"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" onkeyup="validate(event)"/></label>
  <label for="password"><input type="password" id="password" name="password" onkeyup="validate(event)"/></label>
  <button id="btn" value="Submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is nothing to do with HTML, It's for NativeScript, did you read my question?

Comment: @LeeNelson I think the problem is you tagged your question with `JavaScript` and didn't include any example code as you should have, so it is easy to miss that you're wanting something for a specific framework that doesn't seem to be very widely used.

Comment: It's widely used enough to have a tag on stackoverflow. NativeScript uses javascript which is why I tagged it. I didn't include any example code because it didn't need any.

Comment: I apologise for not making it clear enough for you, I guess you should delete your answer as it is off topic to the question.

Comment: @LeeNelson A tag that has only 4,000 questions, so, not widely used. You always need example code because without it it's unclear what you're even doing. Also, this isn't my answer.

Comment: I explained it was for NativeScript in my question and the tags, I can't help if people just scroll past the question without reading it.

Comment: 'Is there a way I can get a function to trigger when input of a text box is changed in NativeScript?' I did specify it was for Native Script.

Comment: @LeeNelson You can use `[class]="(user.email!='' && user.password!='')?'SomeClass':''"` on your button's attribute. Where `user.email` and `user.password` are your controllers model

Comment: @LeeNelson maybe add it to the subject line next time.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my whole answer because I initially gave you a whole demo in Javascript lol. Maybe someone with a lot of reputation points should make a Nativescript tag.

Anyway, have you tried it like this?

```
<TextField hint="Enter text" text="" (textChange)="myFunction($event)"></TextField>
```

**OR**

```
var el = page.getViewById("myEl");
el.on("textChange", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
   console.log('woo');
}
```

And here's some relevant-looking documentation: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/text-field#text-field-binding