# Nativescript how can I send the value of a textfield as a parameter when a change is complete?

Tags: android, html, typescript, nativescript

basically I want to send the value of the textfield to a function every time the user completes a change.  I'm using onchange="..." but I do not know how to grab the value from the textfield itself once its changed in the html/nativescript and I can't find it in the docs.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call function when input is changed on text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469631/call-function-when-input-is-changed-on-text-box)

Comment: I don't see what it's passing through to give the function the value from the textfield?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ddqN7y